# Can I get newly inserted id with sequelize insertOrUpdate?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How can I get newly inserted id with the following sequelize? It currently returns a boolean.

```
exports.update = async note => entityChildModel.insertOrUpdate(note)
    .catch(e => 'Error');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `returning : true` ( to get back auto generated values ) , but it's **only for Postgres** :

```
exports.update = async note => entityChildModel
                                .insertOrUpdate(note , { returning : true }) // <--- HERE
                                .catch(e => 'Error');
```

For more detail : **[DO READ](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-upsert)**